# How to enable VS code extensions while using sshfs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sshfs

I recently started using the sshfs extension by Kelvin Schoofs in VS code and it's a huge time saver. However, my other extentions don't work when I'm editing in the remote workspace.

For example, I have the HTML snippets extension installed and it works when editing a local file. But when I try to use it in a remote workspace it dosen't. Same goes for my other extensions.

I was wondering if anyone had run into this issue and somehow got their other extension to work. I've done some googling around for solutions but haven't found anything that works.

I would also be open to using a different ssh extension if this isn't an issue for the suggested extension.

Thanks in advance for any help or insight you guys can provide.

Comment: Can't you mount your sshfs volume as a disk in your OS? That's what I normally do but I use Mac & Linux. Not sure about Windows

Comment: @slebetman
I'm not familiar with that process. I'll look into it now. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: It looks like there's an open source sshfs driver for Windows - http://www.secfs.net/winfsp/ (warning: I've never used it, just googled it)

Comment: @slebetman Oh wow, that's a really great alternative. Thank you very much for the help.